# `ariaAttributes` config is not working in ExtJS modern toolkit

Tags: extjs, extjs6-modern

This is the [documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.7.0/modern/Ext.Component.html#cfg-ariaAttributes) for ariaAttributes config -

> **ariaAttributes**
>
> An object containing ARIA attributes to be set on this Component's ARIA element. Use this to set the attributes that
> cannot be determined by the Component's state, such as aria-live,
> aria-flowto, etc. Note that this config is only meaningful at the
> Component rendering time, and setting it after that will do nothing.

It's not working, when I tried to use it with `Component`. See fiddle - https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3qp5

Is there any override, anyone is using, to make this config work?